# Cannot move an R chart when generated from C# with RDotNet

Tags: c#, r, visual-studio, charts, r.net

I am using the following C# code to ask R to generate a series of random numbers and plot them as histogram. The code works and the chart appears. The problem is that I cannot do anything with the chart. It is impossible to move it or close it. Then if I go to the end of the code, it disappears. 
Is there a way to make the R chart flexible so that I can move it and do other stuff with it?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using RDotNet;

namespace rgenrand
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        string dllPath = @"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.1\bin\i386\";

        REngine.SetDllDirectory(dllPath);
        REngine.CreateInstance("RDotNet");

        REngine engine = REngine.GetInstanceFromID("RDotNet");
        engine.Initialize();

        var x = engine.Evaluate("x <- rnorm(100, mean=50, sd=10)").AsNumeric();
        engine.Evaluate("hist(x)");
        Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No one can help on this? I can't understand where the problem is with the code since I can't move/resize the R chart.

Comment: Apparently it is possible to move the R chart if the above code is in a Windows Form app instead of a Console app. I have just associated that code to a button and when the chart appears I am able to move it and even access the menu of the R chart.